# How to convert String into string array in C#?

Tags: c#, string

#### I have the following stored in a string.

```
var _status = "Unknown,Enabled,DisabledAccount,Enabled,Password Does Not Expire,Disabled,Password Does Not Expire,Enabled, Password Does Not Expire"
```

#### Desired string so that I can use it in MySQL IN Statement.

```
var stat = "'Unknown','Enabled','Disabled Account','Enabled, Password Does Not Expire','Disabled, Password Does Not Expire','Enabled, Password Does Not Expire'"
```

#### My Code:

```
string stat = "";
string[] devices = _status.Split(',');
foreach (var d in devices)
{
    stat += "'" + d + "',";
}

stat = stat.TrimEnd(',');
```

#### Output

```
var stat = "'Unknown','Enabled','Disabled Account','Enabled',' Password Does Not Expire','Disabled',' Password Does Not Expire','Enabled',' Password Does Not Expire '"
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the problem?  Looks like you got your desired output

Comment: `Regex.Split(_status, "(?<!^),(?!\s)")`

Comment: How would you know that some commas are there as separators and some are part of a sentence. Use another separator (or use a completely different format).

Comment: How do you determine that `Enabled,Password Does Not Expire` must not be split on the comma?

Comment: This will be crazy-vulnerable to sql injection issues.

Comment: Are you asking about `string.Join` ? I'm assuming you mean you want to generate a comma separated string. But look into this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.8 (Again, I'm making an assumption because it's not very clear what you're asking for.)

Comment: Instead of storing it in a format you *don't* want... how about skip the transform and just store it the proper way to begin with?

Comment: Zooming in on your sentence:  "... so that I can use it in MySQL IN Statement." It seems the main thing you're trying to solve is how to pass an array of parameters to a sql statement.  See the duplicate linked and its answer.

Comment: @Mathias R. Jessen  Thanks for the Regex. Worked. Can you put it as an answer so that I can mark it. There was a typo in the Regex though - The corrected RegEx is `Regex.Split(_status, "(?<!^),(?!\\s)")` with two \

Comment: @yodellingbutters Can't post an answer on a closed question, but happy to hear you figured it out :)